# Shared Preferences is not retaining anything

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know this has been asked a lot around SO, but I just can't seem to get this working.
Situation : I have a dialog with a EditText in it with an accept button. I would like to store the value of the string with SharedPreferences when the user touch the accept button. Here's the code I have so far.

```
public void showDialog()
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(VentilationActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu_options);       
    dialog.setTitle("Configuration de l'adresse IP");           
    dialog.setCancelable(true);     
    dialog.show();

    EditText adressIp = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Agrinuvo", 0);  
    String texte = preferences.getString("VentIpKey", "");

    adressIp.setText(texte); 

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(adressIp, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    Button btnAccept = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)                                                         
        {
            EditText adressIp = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
            textIp = adressIp.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("VentIpKey", textIp);
            editor.commit();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(adressIp.getWindowToken(), 0);
            dialog.dismiss();                                                               
        }
    }); 
}
```

And, of course this is not working. Everytime I close the dialog window and reopen it the EditText text is empty. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;

```
public void showDialog() {
    ....
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Agrinuvo", 0);
    ....
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ....
            // Use previous preferences instance instead.
            // SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("VentIpKey", textIp);
            editor.commit();
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, it seems so that you're writing to different preferences than where you read the default value from.

Comment: don't forget to do `preferences = getSharedPreferences("Agrinuvo", 0);` somewhere before the onClick is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `onClickObserver` you create a SharedPreference object for a file named after your activity's class name. At least this is what the Activity's `getPreferences(int)` documentation states. Try instead initializing that object the same way you do it in `showDialog` or making the `showDialog`'s `preferences` final.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there error might be inside your onclick method in the following line

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If you change it to

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Agrinuvo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It should work. The way you were calling it, you weren't getting the same preference that you requesting for your dialog.

Comment: @bali182 Thanks for catching that. I copied and pasted from the question and forgot to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used preferences in my application without too many problems for quite a while and I would suggest a couple things:

getSharedPreferences() should only be used for preferences shared between different Activities.  If only your one Activity will be using the data, use this to save:

```
    SharedPreferences settings  = getPreferences (MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = settings.edit();

    ed.putBoolean ("BooleanKey", booleanVar);
    ed.putInt     ("IntKey", intVar);
    ed.putFloat   ("FloatKey", floatVar);
    ed.putLong    ("LongKey",  longVar);

    ed.commit();
```

And this to retrieve:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences (MODE_PRIVATE);
    longVar = settings.getLong ("longKey", 0);
    ...
```

If you're going to share your preferences across Activites, that's when you'll want to use getSharedPreferences(), but you'll want to NOT user MODE_PRIVATE.  Currently, I use MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE in the code where I write the data and MODE_WORLD_READABLE where I read it, that's probably not the best way (at least, the if the warnings I'm getting from Eclipse are to be believed).

Good luck,
R.